# recent apps button setting on htc one gone?

Tags: settings, htc-one-s

I got a new 
HTC One S / Android 4.03 / Sense 4.0!
via warranty and wanted to set it up.

I wanted to change the setting for recent apps button in
settings > display
but it's not there anymore.

Why? Always had it. Can i somehow get it?

The only things i've done before was unlocking via htcdev, flashing twrp, backing up, restoring backup, restarting, and started installing apps. So it's the original HTC rom and i haven't done changes to rom. Did OTA after didn't found it but still, it's not there.

[image]

Comment: No one knows somehting?

Comment: I installed meanhwile new RUU and it's still not there? Can please someone explain me why this is?

Comment: Ok, installed another RUU and now it's there. I would be ineterested in knowing what this was causing, but for now, i just want to use my phone again and now it works. Different RUU ;-)